# How can I maximize the form at run time

Tags: c#, .net

How can I maximize the form at run time?

I have one panel in form 1 . I want to show form 2 (`Rule_form`) in this panel on button click.

I have write this code on button click:

```
Rule_form rule = new Rule_form();
rule.Show();
rule.TopLevel = false;
rule.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
rule.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

internal_pannel.Controls.Add(rule);
```

But it doesn't work. When I click on button form 2 (`Rule_form`) opens with it's default size.

How can I maximize a form 2 (`Rule_form`) with panel size at start up?

Comment: Why are you adding a form to `Panel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should run rule.Show(); at last.
Because now the form get showed before it is maximized.
That explains your problem.

What if you call rule.show after setting the windowstate or formborderstyle.
That is supposed to work.

You can also create an load event for the new form. And in this load event set the form to be maximized. Like this:

```
private void Rule_form_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```